# Why do so many primes such that $2^q\equiv4\pmod{q+2}$ end in $7$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Originally, I was investigating the divisibility of $p^q-q^p$ by $p+q$ for primes $p,q$, but I quickly discovered that even $p=2$ is not easy at all.

When $p=2$, we have $2^q-q^2\equiv0\pmod{q+2}\iff2^q\equiv4\pmod{q+2}$, or equivalently, $\operatorname{ord}_{q+2}(2)\mid(q-2)$.

We know that $q$ cannot be $3$ modulo $10$, as otherwise it is necessary that $2^{10k+3}\equiv4\pmod5$, but this is a contradiction.

We also see that $q=5$ satisfies the congruence, but subsequent solutions up to $\approx10^{11}$ seem to display a pattern.

\begin{array}{cccccc}\hline\small6462647&\small259195007&\small1654549877&\small22442226767&\small41344905167&\small53085400877&\small86123562527\\\small130647917&\small277628447&\small12746032157&\small\color{red}{22677320759}&\small46649950877&\small77652121367&\small\color{red}{105780380351}\\\small218206487&\small1043030837&\small19745250527&\small26427995687&\small46726848677&\small82396696727&\small149661517007\\\hline\end{array}

Why are solutions with $7$ modulo $10$ so common?

Comment: My guess: since the congruence is equivalent to $2^{q-2}\equiv1\pmod{q+2}$, the more composite $q-2$ is, the better the chances are of this congruence holding. Among odd residue classes modulo $10$, only $q\equiv7\pmod{10}$ forces $q-2$ to have a prime factor (of $5$), making the congruence somewhat more likely.

Comment: @Greg - if that's true, then we should see the same for example for $q \equiv 5 \pmod 6$ or $q \equiv 9 \pmod{14}$.  Of the 21 solutions shown, 19 are 7 mod 10; 12 are 9 mod 14; all 21 are 5 mod 6.  Obviously this isn't a proof but it's evidence in favor of your idea.

Comment: To clarify : What is the prime ? Is it $q$ ?

Comment: As @MichaelLugo observed we always have $q\equiv5\pmod6$. For otherwise $3\mid q+2$, and we would have $2^q\equiv4\equiv1\pmod3$ which is a contradiction.
This implies that always $3\mid q-2$, so the smallest possible factor is there.

Comment: For the listed primes, not entirely unexpectedly, the prime factors $\ell$ of $q+2$ have the property that $2$ has a small (and smooth) order modulo $\ell$. For example with $q=6462647$ we have $q+2=127\cdot151\cdot337$ with $2^7\equiv1\pmod{127}$, $2^{11}\equiv1\pmod{151}$ and $2^{21}\equiv1\pmod{337}$. Also $3,5,7$ are all factors of $q-2$, in line with @GregMartin's prediction.